# Is there a way to look up the method structure of JavaScript in IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I want to see the list of functions defined in a prototype of a JavaScript file. I'm looking for a shortcut like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) it's only supported in the Ultimate editions. I've checked and indeed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> works in java script file there.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Alt + 7** or **Ctrl + f12** will show structure of file include tab JSP, HTML, Java.